# Angularjs on each record open new page on click

Tags: angularjs

this is my angularjs table and response

```
<table class="table myCustomTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Answer</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="intends in data | filter: searchKeyword">
    <td><a href="#/intents/{{intends.id}}">{{intends.name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{intends.answer}}</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

on click name i want to redirect to one page that page

I want deteils about that id

Comment: can you be specific about those "details"? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @My Test, are you using ui-router for navigation? If yes, you can use 'ui-sref' attribute and set target of hyperlink element to _blank.

Answer (score 1):

Use RouterLink directive, it let's you to link to specific parts of your application. refer this [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) documentation for more details.